# Refresh a newly opened window.open from the about:blank

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, window

I open a window after getting data from an ajax result. The below script opens a pdf in a new window only if i resize the window size (manual hotspot resizing) otherwise pdf viewer is not displayed.

How do I make to contents to display on its popup

```
window.open("about:blank")
.document.write(`
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body { 
            margin: 0
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="' + data + '" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0px" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="100%" width="100%">
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
`);
```

Comment: Which browser did you used? using iframe safari is good.

Comment: Are you trying to open a HTTP URL ?, Since chrome consider "about:blank" as HTTPS page chrome will block HTTP URLs loading in iframe

Try replacing  "about:blank" with some other URL or some random string and try

Answer (score -1):

I used aboutblank instead about:blank it worked perfectly.